# ¿Cómo descartar los empleados que cobren menos de 2000 y sean menos de 2 empleados?

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito agrupar  los salarios en tramos de 1000 en 1000, hallar cuántos empleados hay en cada tramo pero hay que descartar los tramos de menos de 2000 euros y que tengan menos de dos empleados.

La tabla TEMPLE contiene:

(NOMEM) Nombre de Empleado
(NUMHI)  Número de Hijos
(NUMEM) Número de Empleado
(NUMDE)  Número de Departamento
(SALAR)  Salario
(COMIS)  Comisión

Yo he intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000 THEN "GRUPO_1"
    WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 3000 AND 4000 THEN "GRUPO_2"
    WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 4000 AND 5000 THEN "GRUPO_3"
    WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 5000 AND 6000 THEN "GRUPO_4"
    END AS SALARIO_GRUPO, COUNT(*) AS EMPLEADOS

FROM
    TEMPLE  
WHERE
    SALAR > 2000
GROUP BY SALARIO_GRUPO;
```

Pero no consigo hacer lo de: "Descartar los tramos de menos de 2000 euros y que tengan menos de dos empleados".

¿Alguna ayidita por favor?

¡Gracias!

Comment: Busca la documentación para HAVING.

Comment: Tu consulta te da algun error?

Comment: Cuando usas consultas de agregación (sum, count...) y quieres aplicar una condición sobre esa agregación tendrás que usar la cláusula HAVING.

Comment: @Soullesito podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util, gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select SALARIO_GRUPO, count(*) as Empleados
(
 SELECT
 CASE
     WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000 THEN "GRUPO_1"
     WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 3000 AND 4000 THEN "GRUPO_2"
     WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 4000 AND 5000 THEN "GRUPO_3"
     WHEN SALAR BETWEEN 5000 AND 6000 THEN "GRUPO_4"
     END AS SALARIO_GRUPO
 FROM TEMPLE          
 WHERE SALAR > 2000        
)
group by SALARIO_GRUPO
having count(*) > 2
```

Haces una **subconsulta** donde solo seleccionarás los salarios mayores a **2000** delimitándolos por los rangos de salario deseados y sobre esta **subconsulta** haces una **consulta general** la cual te va agrupar por cada rango de salario seleccionado en la **subconsulta** y utilizando la **cláusula having** solamente filtrarás los grupos de salario que tengan más de dos trabajadores. La **cláusula having** se parece a la **cláusula where** pero filtra a nivel de las agrupaciones creadas mediante la **clásula group by**.